# Link to your GitHub news feed?

Tags: github

In the android App OctoDroid, you have a tab "News Feed" How do I view my news feed in a browser?

I know the link to my rss atom feed: https://github.com/rubo77.atom but that only contains my activity.

Comment: https://github.com/ ?

Comment: thanks, that was it ;) I never use d the main page ;)
can you add this as answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just visit https://github.com/:

> The feed shows you events from people you follow and repositories you watch.